# Groovy script classpath issue with SystemClassLoader

Tags: groovy, classpath, classloader

I'm writing a Groovy script which uses third party java code that I can't change.
This code uses (badly, I think) `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/hard/file/path/in/jar/file")` 
and expect to read a file.

Everything goes well from Java when using `java -cp "/path/to/jar/file" ...`

However, the third-party code is now to be integrated with a bunch of Groovy code we've already written, so we wanted to run it from groovy.

So we wrote a Groovy script, let it call `test.groovy`, and ran it as `groovy -cp "/path/to/jar/file" test.groovy`.

The problem is that code can't access the file resource, as it seems Groovy doesn't load its jars in the System ClassLoader directly.

For proof, with `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/hard/file/path/in/jar/file")` within the Groovy Script, I can read the file, but with `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/hard/file/path/in/jar/file")`, I can't.

So, does anyone know how to load the class in System ClassLoader from a Groovy Script without beginning to try some dirty hacks (like metaclassing `getSystemClassloader` to return the context classloader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the jar to the system classloader as well when your script runs, like so:

```
ClassLoader.systemClassLoader.addURL new File( '/path/to/jar/file' ).toURI().toURL()
```

PS:  I assume you mean `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` in your question, rather than `System.getSystemClassLoader()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your jar into `%GROOVY_HOME%\lib` folder or make a wrapper around your groovy command and modify `%CLASSPATH%` variable before you start your Groovy process.

Comment: thanks for your answer
%GROOVY_HOME%\lib => already tried, but loaded by GroovyClassLoader
%CLASSPATH% => picked up by Groovy as the `-cp` option